# Anyone succeeded in setting up an IPSEC/L2TP VPN?

Tags: release-freya, vpn

I have been struggling with setting up an IPSEC/L2TP based VPN for a couple of days, and I'm leaning towards that it's broken upstream. After running `sudo apt-get install l2tp-ipsec-vpn`, the `ipsec verify` command shows the following output:

```
Checking your system to see if IPsec got installed and started correctly: 
Version check and ipsec on-path                                 [OK]
Linux Openswan U2.6.38/K(no kernel code presently loaded)
Checking for IPsec support in kernel                            [FAILED]
SAref kernel support                                        [N/A]
Checking that pluto is running                                  [FAILED]
whack: Pluto is not running (no "/var/run/pluto/pluto.ctl")
Checking for 'ip' command                                       [OK]
Checking /bin/sh is not /bin/dash                               [WARNING]
Checking for 'iptables' command                                 [OK]
Opportunistic Encryption Support                                [DISABLED]
```

After running "sudo service ipsec start", this is what "sudo service ipsec status" outputs:

```
IPsec stopped but... has /var/run/pluto/ipsec.info file!
```

My guess so far is that ipsec/openswan somehow expects to find pluto in another location and thus is unable to start it. I can start pluto manually with `/usr/lib/ipsec/pluto --stderrlog`, but for some reason ipsec can't seem to start it.

Has anyone succeeded in setting up an ipsec/l2tp vpn in Freya, and in that case, what did you do to make it work?

Comment: I can confirm that OpenVPN does work.
You can tryit if it suits your needs

Comment: Yes, OpenVPN works fine. Sadly enough, the site in question only offers IPSEC/L2TP so I need to get it working :(

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

First install the following dependencies:

```
sudo apt install git intltool libtool network-manager-dev libnm-util-dev libnm-glib-dev libnm-glib-vpn-dev libnm-gtk-dev libnm-dev libnma-dev ppp-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libsecret-1-dev libgtk-3-dev libglib2.0-dev xl2tpd strongswan libnss3-dev
```

Issue the following on the command-line (note: the backslash character \ is the shell line continuation character which can safely be copy and pasted):

```
git clone https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp.git
cd network-manager-l2tp
autoreconf -fi
intltoolize

./configure \
  --disable-static --prefix=/usr \
  --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
  --libexecdir=/usr/lib/NetworkManager \
  --localstatedir=/var \
  --with-pppd-plugin-dir=/usr/lib/pppd/2.4.7

make
sudo make install
```

source: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789421/l2tp-ipsec-psk-vpn-client-on-xubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Thanks! Works fine on Elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera.